# sp_executesql along with fulltext search and formsof inflectional

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, sp-executesql

I'm trying to perform sp_executesql with fulltext search in it.

This query was working fine.

```
exec sp_executesql 
    N'SELECT TOP (@p0)  this_.org_id as y0_, this_.u_Name as y1_, this_.Category as y2_ FROM Organization this_ 
    WHERE contains (this_.u_Name,@p1)'
    ,N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(4000)',
    @p0=1000,@p1=N'service'
```

But I had to add a formsof inflectional for word variations and then it look like the parameter @p1 is now blank and the query return no results. Any reason ? If I replace @p1 with the actual word "service", everything works fine.

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'SELECT TOP (@p0)  this_.org_id as y0_, this_.u_Name as y1_, this_.Category as y2_ FROM Organization this_ 
WHERE contains (this_.u_Name,''formsOf(inflectional, @p1)'')'
,N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(4000)',
@p0=1000,@p1=N'service'
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the formsOf() your variable @p1 turned into a string.  Try this:

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'declare @ft nvarchar(4000)
set @ft = ''formsof(inflectional, '' + quotename(@p1, ''"'') + '')''
SELECT TOP (@p0)  this_.org_id as y0_, this_.u_Name as y1_, this_.Category as y2_ FROM Organization this_ 
WHERE contains (this_.u_Name,@ft)'
,N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(4000)',
@p0=1000,@p1=N'service'
```